# Fragment returned two views

Tags: android, android-fragments

i had impemented fragment in my project. I added an ImageButton in my fragment XML. But when i inflated it to my activity there is two buttons in my layout activity. Why my fragment returned two views? and how to fix it have to normal view like in my fragment XML? Thanks in advance.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLVGf.jpg)
*I am sorry i can not upload image, my reputations is not enough

You can look at the picture, there is 2 buttons. I just want one button.

below is my activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.candlelightstudio.letsbesmartkid.ToolbarAbout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_pilihsoal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

below is my fragment xml, named toolbar_about

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_ToolAbout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />

</LinearLayout>
```

below is ToolbarAbout.java

```
package com.candlelightstudio.letsbesmartkid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;

public class ToolbarAbout extends Fragment {
    private FragmentAbout about;
    private FragmentManager fm;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_about, container, false);
        ImageButton tool = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_ToolAbout);
        final Context c = inflater.getContext();
        about = new FragmentAbout();
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        tool.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                about.show(fm, "About");
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

below is piece of my activity.java for inflate the fragment

```
Fragment fr = new ToolbarAbout();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

SOLVED
Only delete the code for inflating fragment, and it's work properly

delete this code

```
Fragment fr = new ToolbarAbout();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

cause i have declare a class for my fragment, here :

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.candlelightstudio.letsbesmartkid.ToolbarAbout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

you can see i added **android:name="com.candlelightstudio.letsbesmartkid.ToolbarAbout"**

Thanks a lot @Manpreet Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the ToolbarAbout fragment will be inflated automatically in your app since you provided the following line in your xml :

```
 android:name="com.candlelightstudio.letsbesmartkid.ToolbarAbout
```

so there is no need to replace fragment for this so remove these lines from activity :

```
Fragment fr = new ToolbarAbout();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: wuuutsss, -___- thanks bro. it's work. I do not think of this. This is trivial things , I 'm ashamed been asking trivia caused my mistake in this forum . Thanks @Manpreet Singh

Comment: I am sorry @Manpreet Singh my reputations is not enough to vote up your answer. I'll be back to vote up yours when my reps have enough hihihi :D

Comment: @Agi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark because it doest need any reputation . This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: done bro. I dont know about that check mark is shortcur for marked answer contain the solution hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You add the fragment via code and **xml**. For example to do it through code only, you'd change the `fragment` view to a container:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: but when i delete android:name="com.candlelightstudio.letsbesmartkid.ToolbarAbout" the app for stopped and in log cat i found error description said that "error inflating class fragment" @user3249477